# jquery run each only one time

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have a piece of code that depends on the scroll position, runs. Problem is that it runs every time the user is scrolling, which is annoying, so I want to be able to only run the functionality only one time, if the if statement(the one i did in the example) is true.

Example of my code:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
            var     top     = this.scrollY,
                    posWeb  = $('section#web').position().top;

            if(top > posWeb){
                $('div.test').each(function(){
                    $(this).animate({
                        width:'100%'
                    }, 1000);
                });
            }
        }, false);
```

I have tried putting one() before the each function, but unfortunately that does not work. Suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple flag variable will take care of it.

```
var animated=false;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var top = this.scrollY,
        posWeb = $('section#web').position().top;
    // new condition added
    if (top > posWeb && !animated) {
        animated = true; // set true now so animations don't get attempted again
        $('div.test').each(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                width: '100%'
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
}, false);
```

`one()` is only used for events, not animations

Comment: Oh off course. How come I didn't thought of that? Thanks a lot :-)